# Django TemplateSyntaxError when combining template tags

Tags: django, django-templates

Let say users can access the following urls in Django,

```
someUrl/one
someUrl/two
someUrl/three
```

one, two, and three comes from a table such that I can access them with the ORM for example, tableName.number. My question is how do I write them in my template,I tried with

```
<source src="{% static "someUrl/"{{ tableName.number }} "%}"/>
```

but I am getting a TemplateSyntaxError.

```
Could not parse the remainder: 'someUrl/" {{ tableName.number }} "' from '" "someUrl/" {{ tableName.number }} "'
```

If I try

```
<source src="{% static "someUrl/{{ tableName.number }}" "%}"/>
```

I get

```
Could not parse the remainder: 'audio/{{' from '" "audio/{{'
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I updated with error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot nest variables in django templates. Try this

```
<source src='{% static "someUrl" %}/{{ tableName.number }}' />
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`add` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#add)

Example:

```
{% static 'someurl'|add:tableName.number %}
```

Comment: just a follow up question, is there any way to strip tableName.number inside the template like in python's strip function because my tableName.number has some leading characters for example tableName.number = aaa/bbb/one I just need the 'one'? aaa/bbb/one comes from a FilePathField.

Comment: If you are doing complicated things such as this, I would encourage you to look into a custom templatetag.